# How do I run rake rake tasks in a rails app which is served by tomcat with jruby war deployment?

Tags: rake, jrubyonrails

I have a rails application deployed to tomcat, the code has been compiled to java classes and packed to a war file. And I'm wondering, is there a way for me to run rake tasks as I always did ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like a convenient way of doing this too, although I'm not sure it's possible.

From the exploded (unzipped) WAR, you can get somewhere with this kind of thing:

```
  java -cp WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-1.6.4.jar -S rake
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-1.6.4.jar -S rake
```

This worked for me. Possibly the same as the previous answer, but I do not know enough about java, .war files, or jruby, to say in any certainty.