# Running Rake Tasks under Tomcat and JRuby

Tags: tomcat, rake, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

We've got our Rails (2.2.2) application running on a Tomcat7 server using warbler (1.2.1) and JRuby (1.5.6), but since we want to simplify deployment to multiple machines, we want to run the rake tasks, like `db:migrate`, under the tomcat WEB-INF location. We have packaged up the db folder along with all the migrations.

One way we've seen recommended online doesn't work:

```
java -jar lib/jruby-core-1.5.6.jar -S $JRUBY_HOME/bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging

/var/lib/jruby/bin/rake:9:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
        from /var/lib/jruby/bin/rake:9
```

After adding to ENV:

```
GEM_HOME=$JRUBY_HOME/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
RUBYLIB=$JRUBY_HOME/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
```

The same command gives:

```
/var/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:32 warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/var/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require': no such file to load -- fileutils (LoadError)
        from /var/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /var/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:35
        from /var/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:31:in `require'
        from /var/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /var/lib/jruby-1.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:29
        from /var/lib/jruby-1.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:19:in `load'
        from /var/lib/jruby/bin/rake:19
```

And if I just run:

```
jruby -S $JRUBY_HOME/bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging
```

I get a big callstack of gem errors resulting from the vendorized gems. (OutOfMemoryError, NUllPointerException, etc.. which isn't actually consistent between runs).

This question ([How do I run rake rake tasks in a rails app which is served by tomcat with jruby war deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296033/how-do-i-run-rake-rake-tasks-in-a-rails-app-which-is-served-by-tomcat-with-jruby)) had no bites on it either. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this command works

```
java -jar /var/lib/jruby/jruby-complete-1.5.6.jar -S rake  db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging
```

as long as I download the jruby-complete jar and make sure I have the ENV:

```
RUBYLIB=$JRUBY_HOME/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
GEM_HOME=$JRUBY_HOME/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Comment: This is interesting. GEM_HOME just has a bunch of gem files, which get packed up in the WEB-INF directory. However, RUBYLIB seems to have a bunch of ruby related files. When I deploy to Tomcat, the intention is to deploy no ruby-related stuff except the war file. What are the necessary files in RUBYLIB to make this work? If I know, I can just twiddle config/warble.rb to include them.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well, but on Windows.

Based on [this warbler issue](https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/128), I was able to put together a Windows batch script to include in the deploy and make the DB setup simple for our SAs:

```
SET RAILS_ENV=production
SET BUNDLE_WITHOUT=development:test
SET BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile
SET GEM_HOME=gems
java -classpath "lib/*" org.jruby.Main -S rake db:create db:migrate db:seed
pause
```

Running this from the WEB-INF directory of the deployed app does the trick.  I did need to add the db directory, Rakefile, and Windows batch script to my warble.rb config to make it all play nicely.

[kares](https://github.com/kares) is actively working hard to get proper rake support in warbler, so this should be a "for now" answer (and there are certainly cleaner ways to go about it if I wasn't pressed by a deadline), but I figured I'd share anyway since it was a stumbling point.